# Array of optional ?? NSNull() - Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I added a SDK in my project which has problem with this method. it says that the operation is too complex and I should divide it.
I have 3 questions:

1. Is this compile error related to the swift version, I mean that is this error exist in different swift versions or not?
2. why should some one writes NSNULL when nil exist in a variable?
3. If I want to resolve the problem temporary (till the sdk updates) what should I do?

Error:

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider
>   breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Code:

```
import SwiftyJSON

func toJSON() -> JSON {
        var result: JSON = ["id": id ?? NSNull(),
                            "uId": uId ?? NSNull(),
                            // ten other elements ]
        return result
}
```

Comment: What is `JSON`?

Comment: @Carpsen90 It is declared in SwiftyJSON.

Comment: Since the introduction of `Codable` any *from-and-to-JSON* library looks quite poor . Actually libraries like `SwiftyJSON` and `ObjectMapper` became obsolete. Use `Codable`.

Comment: You should mention that in your question, and as Mr Vadian says, Codable structs are much easier to use

Comment: @Carpsen90 ok thanks

Comment: “I added a SDK in my project” so you are saying this is not your code? Whose code is it then? Is it SwiftyJson? If so, there’s your answer. Don’t use it. Its day is past.

Comment: @matt Thanks. No its not SwiftyJson, but it uses it. I have to use this sdk, its not for json.

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't think so. I believe this is compiler problem

2) You cannot add nil inside collections, so if you want to put a 'filler', NSNull is usually used

3) Use a JSON initializer

```
    let item1: (String, Any) = ("id", id ?? NSNull())
    let result = JSON(elements: item1, item2, ... )

    return result
```